# How to remove line break after first word, css?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I’m creating an email in html/css to send to people on a mailing list and everything works fine except that on mobile devices the line breaks after the first word for every paragraph like this.

[image: example photo]

The code was generated by an email template generator online and is as shown below. I'm pretty sure that about 80% of it is redundant.

```html
<td style="padding:18px 0px 0px 0px; line-height:22px; text-align:inherit;" height="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="" role="module-content">
   <div>
      <div style="font-family: inherit; text-align: left">
         <span style="box-sizing: border-box; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant-ligatures: inherit; font-variant-caps: inherit; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: baseline; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-top-style: initial; border-right-style: initial; border-bottom-style: initial; border-left-style: initial; border-top-color: initial; border-right-color: initial; border-bottom-color: initial; border-left-color: initial; border-image-source: initial; border-image-slice: initial; border-image-width: initial; border-image-outset: initial; border-image-repeat: initial; text-align: center; color: #516775; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: pre-wrap; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 254, 254)">Dear {{contact}}, Please print out this sheet and display at entry point.&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
</td>
```

What css element can I add to get rid of this, or alternatively what css element should I remove to get rid of this effect?

Comment: I think you have to change the `white-space` property on the `span` from `pre-wrap` to `normal`: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `white-space: pre-wrap;`  and everything should work as expected.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space